# When and why would i use abs in c++

Tags: c++, cmath

So, I was looking at some open source code that searches through a random set of numbers to find the closest number to 0. And for some reason it uses abs in the  library a bit, and I was wondering when why and where I would use it. Here is the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int N; // the number of temperatures to analyse
  cin >> N; cin.ignore();

  if( N == 0 ) {
        cout << 0 << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    int bestTemp = 5527;
    for( int i = 0; i < N; i++ ) {
        int v;
        cin >> v;
        if( abs( v ) < abs( bestTemp ) ) {
            bestTemp = v;
        } else if( abs( v ) == abs( bestTemp ) && bestTemp < 0 ) {
            bestTemp = v;
        }
    }


    // Write an action using cout. DON'T FORGET THE "<< endl"
    // To debug: cerr << "Debug messages..." << endl;

    cout << bestTemp << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I got this code from codingame and the user I found this from was Bob.
P.S I am pretty young so could you make it easier for me to understand, please and thank you.

Comment: Did you try reading [documentation for abs()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/abs/) to see what it does?

Comment: As with any other function, you use it when you require the functionality it provides, and never any time else.

Comment: when they want to get the absolute value?

Comment: Re: `// Write an action using cout. DON'T FORGET THE "<< endl"` -- on the contrary, **forget** the `std::endl`, unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Answer (score 2):

`abs()` gives the [absolute value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value) of a number, which means it makes negative numbers positive.

Since `abs( v )` and `abs( bestTemp )` return the positive version of both numbers, `abs( v ) < abs( bestTemp )` will be true if `v` is lower in magnitude (or "closer to 0") than `bestTemp`.